# Table inside a table in HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I have a design, where a table is inside another table in such a way that if i click on a particular TD in a TR, a new table will be coming between that TR and the next TR. What happens is that, the TR that comes after the TR(which contains the inside table), are all not part of the table structure, which its suppose to be.[image]

Here is the CODE

```
HTML
<div class="table-responsive">
                                    <p class="t_heading">Details</p>
                                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <th>Date</th>
                                            <th>Time</th>
                                            <th>RID</th>
                                            <th>Transaction ID</th>
                                            <th>Description</th>
                                            <th>Ticket Status</th>
                                            <th>Details</th>                                                
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>23 Jan 2015</td>
                                                <td>13:00</td>
                                                <td>5221187</td>
                                                <td>000765487</td>
                                                <td>Bad Network</td>
                                                <td>Pending</td>
                                                <td><a href="#" class="ct_report_details">SHOW DETAILS</a></td>                         
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr style="display:none">
                                                <table class="table">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <th>Date</th>
                                                        <th>Time</th>
                                                        <th>MSISDN</th>
                                                        <th>RID</th>
                                                        <th>Account</th>
                                                        <th>Operator</th>
                                                        <th>Status</th>
                                                        <th>Amount</th>
                                                        <th><a href="#" class="ct_report_details_refund">Refund</a></th>
                                                        <th><a href="#">Close</a></th>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <td>3 Jan 2015</td>
                                                        <td>12:00</td>
                                                        <td>987765466</td>
                                                        <td>5111876</td>
                                                        <td>907765433</td>
                                                        <td>BSNL</td>
                                                        <td>Pending</td>
                                                        <td><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>&nbsp675546</td>
                                                        <td><a href="#" class="ct_report_details_refund">3 Jan 2015</a></td>
                                                        <td><a href="#"> Jan 2015</a></td>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>23 Jan 2015</td>
                                                <td>13:00</td>
                                                <td>5221187</td>
                                                <td>000765487</td>
                                                <td>Bad Network</td>
                                                <td>Pending</td>
                                                <td><a href="#" class="ct_report_details">SHOW DETAILS</a></td>                         
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>23 Jan 2015</td>
                                                <td>13:00</td>
                                                <td>5221187</td>
                                                <td>000765487</td>
                                                <td>Bad Network</td>
                                                <td>Pending</td>
                                                <td><a href="#" class="ct_report_details">SHOW DETAILS</a></td>                         
                                            </tr>                                                                                                                   
                                        </tbody>                                                                                                    
                                    </table>                                        
                                </div>
```

Comment: please give your javascript/ jQuery code.

Comment: there is no Javascript. its just a table with a bootstrap class.

Comment: You need to use a td after tr.

Answer (score 1):

As 'Konok' Commented on my questiong, there should be a TD to the TR, and the colspan of the TD should be 7, since there are 7 columns in parent table.

_thanks you all for the support.

```
<tr style="display:none">
 <td colspan="7">
  <table class="table custom-view">
  <thead>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>MSISDN</th>
      <th>RID</th>
      <th>Account</th>
      <th>Operator</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th><a href="#" class="ct_report_details_refund">Refund</a></th>
      <th><a href="#">Close</a></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <td>3 Jan 2015</td>
      <td>12:00</td>
      <td>987765466</td>
      <td>5111876</td>
      <td>907765433</td>
      <td>BSNL</td>
      <td>Pending</td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>&nbsp675546</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="ct_report_details_refund">3 Jan 2015</a></td>
      <td><a href="#"> Jan 2015</a></td>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like that:

add a class named: **custom-view**

```
<tr style="display:none">
  <table class="table custom-view">
      <thead>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th>MSISDN</th>
          <th>RID</th>
          <th>Account</th>
          <th>Operator</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th><a href="#" class="ct_report_details_refund">Refund</a></th>
          <th><a href="#">Close</a></th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <td>3 Jan 2015</td>
          <td>12:00</td>
          <td>987765466</td>
          <td>5111876</td>
          <td>907765433</td>
          <td>BSNL</td>
          <td>Pending</td>
          <td><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>&nbsp675546</td>
          <td><a href="#" class="ct_report_details_refund">3 Jan 2015</a></td>
          <td><a href="#"> Jan 2015</a></td>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</tr>
```

Javascript Code here:

```
<script>
    $(".your-click-event").on("click", function(){
      $(".custom-view").css({ "display" : "table-cell" });
    })

</script>
```